# Paramiko SSHClient.connect fails while SSH works

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

in the terminal, the following works just fine:

```
> ssh me@host -p 22
```

but the following python code gives me a TimeoutError:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
client = SSHClient()
client.connect(hostname='host', port=22, username='me', look_for_keys=True)
```

Any idea why that would be the case? The connection uses RSA keys for authentication, and I'm over a VPN. Seems like I'm missing some context I need to tell paramiko about, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: do you have any conf in `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 1):

I usually connect to a remote server by adding an explicit link to my private key:

```
HOST = 'hostname'
USER = 'username'
PKEY = '/path/to/rsa_private_key'
PKEY_PASS = 'xxx'

k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(PKEY, PKEY_PASS)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "connecting"
ssh.connect(HOST, username=USER, pkey=k)
connect_status = 'connected' if ssh else 'failed to connect'
print connect_status
```

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is I'm doing this from a company laptop, and I'm not the one who generated the key and thus I do not know the key's password. I assume that's by design, and I'm reticent to generate a new key.

Comment: Do you know where the key is located? `look_for_keys` is looking in `~/.ssh`. You could try naming the key explicitly with the `key_filename` argument instead.